# How to reference a component of another GameObject in inspector window?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The component needs to be referenced in an array.But if I directly drag the GameObject in the variable field, the default component is Transform. In the picture below, the component I want to assign is Skinned Mesh Renderer, instead of Transform.[enter image description here](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Exuyichang/issues/array.png)

Comment: What type is your array?

Comment: If you are using a collection of `Component` then Unity will use the first component that matches the type .. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71995385/7111561) provides a good solution for this .. but I would rather make sure your collection has a proper type .. it is a bit unclear what this is supposed to be used for in the end

Answer (score 1):

if you use:

```
[SerializeField] private List<Component> components;
```

you can fill the components via drag & drop.

An easy way is:

- lock the inspector (upper right corner)
- open a second inspector-window (via "add tab")
- drag & drop the components

Comment: Locking is a good operation. Thanks.